# qtwebkit 5.9.0 required unicode headers

Tags: qtwebkit

```
/tmp/12/qtwebkit-opensource-src-5.9.0/Source/WTF/wtf/unicode/icu/UnicodeIcu.h:29:27: fatal error: unicode/uchar.h: No such file or directory
 #include <unicode/uchar.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [.obj/llint/LLIntOffsetsExtractor.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/12/qtwebkit-opensource-src-5.9.0/build/Source/JavaScriptCore'
make[1]: *** [sub-LLIntOffsetsExtractor-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/12/qtwebkit-opensource-src-5.9.0/build/Source/JavaScriptCore'
make: *** [sub-Source-JavaScriptCore-JavaScriptCore-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

Comment: Same problem here building a yocto poky distro with rocko branch, I don't know how to manage that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install icu libraries, for detailed operation you can Check the url below:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/39332/i-try-compile-qtwebkit

Comment: While this links to a forum post, there is no listed solution.